# IOS: Call can throw, but is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: swift

After googling this topic and reading other people's answers to other topics and implementing their suggestions into mine, I still can't figure this out.

In my code:

```
import Foundation

protocol WeatherServiceDelegate {
     func setWeather(weather: Weather) 
}

class WeatherService {
     var delegate: WeatherServiceDelegate?

     func getWeather(city: String) {
         let path = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1"
         let url = URL(string: path)!
         let session = URLSession.shared
         let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
             if let data = data {
                 //print(">>>>\(data)")

                 let json = JSON(data: data)
             }
         }

         task.resume()
      }  
}
```

I get the error from this line. The little red arrow is right under the 'J' in JSON...

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
```

And the error being:

> Call can throw, but is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Comment: you need to place everything inside the data {} bracket inside of a do {} catch{} block, and change `let json = JSON(data: data)` to `let json = try JSON(data: data)`

Comment: Read the swing language guide. Seriously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is the following.

```
var json: [AnyHashable:Any]?

do {
    json = try JSON(data: data)
} catch _ {
    json = nil
}
```

What xcode is trying to say is that calling the `JSON(data: data)` can throw an error and you should put it inside a `try-catch`

Comment: Unfortunately I get more errors...

Comment: What is it saying ?

Comment: @HarrySingh There's no point using `try?` if you're going to `catch`. Either use `try`, or remove the `catch`.

Comment: yeah my bad @Alexander

Comment: @HarrySingh That whole thing can be replaced with `let son = try? JSON(data: data)`

Comment: @HarrySingh Also, `[:]?` isn't a valid type

Comment: if let data = data{
            //print(">>>>\(data)")
                var json: [:]?
                do{
                json = JSON(data: data)
               
                } catch _ {
                    json = nil
                }
            }

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to format that

Comment: Try the updated answer @J.Derbs

Comment: Should I delete task.resume() then? That's the only error left. the error is "Variable used within its own initial value" ?

Comment: Although task.resume is needed. It helps pull info from the url.

Comment: No don't delete it but you need to move it outside of the completion. It needs to be at the same level as the `let task = ` and `let sesstion = URLSession.shared`.